# How can I edit pages from my local environment?

Tags: pages, editor, wp-editor, localhost

Is there any to edit and/or create wordpress pages from my local environment? Or shall I use the wordpress editor no matter what?

Answer (score 2):

From my view, I avoid using the wp editor at all. It doesn't offer all the good things a IDE can provide.

If you have a local server running, you probably can access it. For example, in linux its usally on `/var/www/localhost/htdocs/` but it varies a lot from distro to distro.

You can also use a IDE and push the modifications via ssh or ftp to your remote.

Without more details on your local environment, I can only suggest reading this:

[**The best-way-to-edit-wordpress-files**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/whats-the-best-way-to-edit-wordpress-files?rq=1)

Comment: well, I already am working on a wordpress website in my local environment. I set up apache, mysql. I track the code with Git and push it to a server. I modify all the theme files with Vim. I just have no idea how I can create a wordpress page from localhost. I'm not even sure it is possible.

Comment: Are you talking about actual content, like writing a post or article, or code?

Comment: I am talking about these [pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages). Yes, actual content, but since they often will have code inside I'd like to edit theme in my local environment.

Comment: in that case, its recommended that you use editor.  You can edit the database, using something like phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by create a page in localhost? You can create pages easily. Do you mean that you want to view the page in localhost? If that is your aim, then you have to run the index.php in the root folder. Not he one in the themes folder. When I make WordPress site, I like to download a naked theme and use it as a skeleton. My favorite is  [Starkers Naked theme](https://github.com/viewportindustries/starkers)